# Is there a fundamental difference from creating a model for each value in a category?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am creating a few models based on service requests. The services being requested are not distributed equally, some services being used sparingly, whereas others are quite common.

I had these services as categorical variables and built pipelines to incorporate them through one-hot encoding. I got to thinking that it may make more sense to train a model per service(at least for the common ones). Or does it make more sense to lump in the less common ones in a special category?

I am struggling with the regression model, coming in at 0.41 for my R2 value.

Comment: what's your prediction target? you are using regression but it sounds like you try to predict the service category? or are they inputs to the model?

Comment: I am doing a variety of models and in most cases, it would be an input. For example, I am trying to predict how long it will take to implement, whether a specific group needs to be involved to provide customization. In other cases, the target is actually the product (as you had correctly guessed), but that situation does not apply to my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a fundamental difference from creating a model for each value in a category?

Yes there is.

If a model is trained for each specific value of a variable (a category), then only the subset of data for this category can be used to train and test the model. As a consequence each model has a smaller number of instances to be trained from. Consequences:

- In the case of a small category, there might not be enough instances to obtain a reliable model.
- Every model is independent. This can be good or bad depending on whether this independence is also true in the data or not, or to what extent:

  - If the features behave in a completely different way depending on the category, then it's better to create individual models since each can really exploit the specific patterns for this category.
  - If the features have a very similar behavior across the categories, then independent models by category would potentially lose a lot of information.

In conclusion the choice often depends on:

- How much data is available for each category.
- How independent are the other features with respect to the category.